# Question about false discovery rate with Benjamini-Hochberg-adjusted p-values and classifier false positive rate

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons

Suppose one is testing multiple hypotheses and, for a given FDR, computes Benjamini-Hochberg adjusted p-values. Furthermore, consider the classifier defined by $f(p; t) = \{\text{True if } p \ge t; \text{else False}\}$ where $p$ is the p-value from the statistical test and the classes are "null hypothesis is rejected" and "not rejected".

My question is: at the adjusted p-value threshold corresponding to the FDR, would we expect the classifier's false positive rate to equal the FDR?

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to understand this scenario. Is the idea that all assumptions of the underlying statistical tests are met, you compute the p-values for each test, feed them into your p-value adjustment machine, and then use your classifier to reject anything with _p ≥t_ and "accept?" when _p<t_, and your "false positive" means "reject" when null is true?

Comment: Are you assuming anything about the true proportion of time the null hypothesis is actually true?